# Uniqueness of solutions to an specific ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

I'm trying to obtain information about the following system of ODEs, where $c_1, c_2$ are constants and $h_1, h_2: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth positive functions defined on an open interval:

$$
 \begin{cases}
 c_1h_2\left(1-(h_1)^2 \right) - h_1 (h_1)'' h_2 - (r_1 - 1) (h_1')^2 h_2 - r_2 h_1 h_1' h_2' = 0  \\
 c_2h_1\left(1-(h_2)^2 \right) - h_2 (h_2)'' h_1 - (r_2 - 1) (h_2')^2 h_1 - r_1 h_2 h_2' h_1' = 0 
 \end{cases}
$$

It is clear (dividing by $h_2$ or $h_1$ on the first or second, equation, respectively) that once one has initial value conditions and one determines $h_1$ (resp. $h_2$), then $h_2$ is determined as well. But I would like to know whether there is any kind of uniqueness of solutions in this situation: i.e., if $\psi_1, \psi_2$ also satisfy this system, is it true that $h_1 = \psi_1$ and $h_2 = \psi_2$? If not, are there any conditions we can impose on the system so that the solutions are unique?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the equations as $h_1'' = \ldots$ and $h_2'' = \ldots$, and the standard Existence and Uniqueness theorem for systems of differential equations applies.  The only wrinkle is that to do this we must divide by $h_1 h_2$, so that things may go bad if $h_1$ or $h_2$ hits $0$.  But on any interval where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are strictly positive, solutions are uniquely determined by initial conditions of the form $h_1(t_0) = a$, $h_2(t_0) = b$, $h_1'(t_0) = c$, $h_2'(t_0)=d$.

Comment: My hypothesis for the problem are tht $h_1$ and $h_2$ are always strictly positve, so no problem there. I thought the standard existence and uniqueness theorems only applied to linear equations, but I guess I was wrong then. Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).  This states the theorem for a first-order system: you can make your second-order system into a first-order one by using new dependent variables 
$h_3 = h_1'$ and $h_4 = h_2'$.